# Need help with 2D textures on CUDA. Not getting the expected value for the indexes I want

Tags: c++, cuda, texture2d

I have two matrices (A and B), 2-dimensions. And i think i'll speed up a bit if instead of putting it into global memory and access via pointers, i put them into textures 2d and use it. The matrices aren't that big, and different positions are read by different threads.

So right now my code is using global memory, and the values i get are correct, i am multiplying for every value in the matrix:

`A[i][j] * B[ p[i] ] [ p[j] ]`

The optimal value for the instance i'm testing is `9552`, can't get a different value.

So i moved into textures, and it seems like some fetches return a wrong value, because i got a `9511` right now.

I was searching about textures on CUDA, and i saw they are indexed by [0..n-1]. But they have some normalized access, and a couple other stuff, like filtering, where the value you want is an interpolation of neighbors.

What's the default options for a texture? Maybe that's the problem. Couldn't find the defaults on the Programming Guide.

here's the relevant code:

Declaration:

```
texture<float,2> A_matrix;
texture<float,2> B_matrix;
```

Allocation:

```
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&_A, n * n * sizeof(float) ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&_B, n * n * sizeof(float) ) );
```

Memcpy

```
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( _A, A, n * n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( _B, B, n * n * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
```

Binding and Descriptors (created two because i'm silly)

```
cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaChannelFormatDesc desc2 = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaBindTexture2D( NULL, A_matrix,
                                   _A,
                                   desc, n, n,
                                   sizeof(float) * n ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaBindTexture2D( NULL, B_matrix,
                                   _B,
                                   desc2, n, n,
                                   sizeof(float) * n ) );
```

And where i use it

```
res += tex2D(A_matrix, i, j)  * tex2D(B_matrix, p[i], p[j]);
```

So how can I use textures correctly? Or are they meant to be like this?

**EDIT:**

This is the code that uses this memory access, the commented line doesn't use textures, and WORKS PERFECTLY.

```
__device__ inline float datastruct::getPermutationValue(int* p)
{
    float res = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ints[data_n] ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < ints[data_n] ; j++)
            res += tex2D(A_matrix, i, j)  * tex2D(B_matrix, p[i], p[j]);
            //res += qap_A[i * ints[data_n] + j]  * qap_B[p[i] * ints[data_n] + p[j]];
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming res is in your global kernel - can you show how you defined i and j? try setting:
A_Matrix.addressMode[0]=cudaAddressModeWrap;
A_Matrix.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeWrap;
A_Matrix.filterMode= cudaFilterModePoint;
And also you may want to make sure you add a 0.5f offset to i and j(i+=0.5f;...)

Comment: @Marm0t, edited my question and added the function code that does the memory accesses. Where should i put `A_Matrix.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeWrap;` ? host code or device code? anywhere?

Comment: this should be on your host code. Sorry I didn't mean wrap either - you should be doing point mode - i.e. A_Matrix.addressMode[0]=cudaAdressModePoint. Read the docs on this in the nvidia cuda programming help, but this should address one of your issues.

Comment: @Marm0t, i was looking at the cuda headers, and there is no cudaAddressModePoint declared, the enum has `enum cudaTextureAddressMode
{
  cudaAddressModeWrap   = 0,    /**< Wrapping address mode */
  cudaAddressModeClamp  = 1,    /**< Clamp to edge address mode */
  cudaAddressModeMirror = 2,    /**< Mirror address mode */
  cudaAddressModeBorder = 3     /**< Border address mode */
};`

Comment: ah sorry again I wasn't looking at the docs... you want Clamp. It won't change anything unless you are accessing out of bounds indexes (but you probably won't).

Comment: @Marm0t, there is another problem, i can't set the texture settings like you said, by just setting `A_matrix.foo = bar;`. VS says it wasn't declared, and it was declared as a global variable and before this actual code. If i want to use it like that, i'm going to have to call `cudaGetTextureReference()`, manually set the attributes,  and bind it in a different way. This just keeps getting harder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry 2D textures in CUDA can be a pain. I have a simple code thats only about 150 lines. I posted it on the [nvidia forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=186838). I believe you may need one of the sdk libraries to compile. I haven't had too much luck with textures for more complicated operations. I hope this helps you, it should compile for you.

Comment: yes it works (just try to compile and run). I was trying the 'wrap' address mode (why I sent that first response) to see how it handled periodicity. It compiles and runs, you can copy paste it and try running as long as you link it to the correct cuda /cudasdk library.

where you see "float u=(idx-1.0f)/float(width);"
you could replace with "float u=(idx+0.5f)/float(width);"
What I had done in the example is shift all the data in the array I defined. I hope this is a good starting point for you.

Comment: ok, i'll try that later, i'm focused on other optimizations right now.. wish i had a 2.0 CUDA GPU, first thing i'm  buying next year if my master degree uses CUDA. Can you explain me the concept of the `pitch` in the memory? the only `pitch` I know is from mixing, to make it faster or slower, can't understand it's use in the memory copy/allocation. I translated it to portuguese and i got `step`, but i don't know what it actually does. Thanks ;)

Comment: Alright! this really helped me, the main thing here is passing the pitch you got from the cudaMallocPitch to the bindTexture2D, now i can access stuff from the texture like `float A_ = tex2D(A_matrix, i, j);`, don't even have to add `0.5f`.. and oh boy.. i got like a 2x speedup :D

Comment: glad this helped, its unfortunate nvidia doesn't have better documentation for using textures!

Answer (score 1):

Textures are born from a need in graphics and as such there are some idiosyncracies defined by the standards. In this case you are probably encountering an issue with the coordinates you are providing, in that you not hitting an exact point. Try this:

```
res += tex2D(A_matrix, i+0.5f, j+0.5f)  * tex2D(B_matrix, p[i]+0.5f, p[j]+0.5f);
```

Incidentally, you should consider using pitched memory or CUDA arrays to improve performance, see the CUDA Programming Guide and Reference Manual for more information.

Comment: CUDA arrays? what are those? I'm only aware of global, shared, constant, texture and surface memories. I'm gonna try to find something about pitched memories. Also, i'm gonna try adding that `0.5f` to my indexes, I'll post a response soon. Thanks ;)

Comment: CUDA arrays are still just global data arrays, but the rows and columns are arranged to improve performance when accessing, especially via a texture. Check out the programming guide for more information.

Comment: @Tom, Oh.. i remember.. CUDA arrays have their own functions for allocating and copying, right? Didn't have time to test the `0.5f` sum to get the right value, but i'll definitely check those CUDA array functions. Thanks.

Comment: @polar: if you get a chance to test the +0.5f please come back here and let the community know whether it helped.

Comment: @Tom: I will, i just need to get back home. Just really want it to work.